# php upload file and adding it name to a column of database but how to change the name autoincrement

Tags: php

table :

```
id, name, filename
1   ab    temp1.pdf
2   cd    temp2.pdf
...................
```

class:

```
public function attach_file($file){
  if(!$file || empty($file){
     $this->errors[] = "No file";
  } else {
      $this-temp_path = $file['tmp_name'];
      $this->filename = basename($file['name']);
}
```

this will upload my file but here on the **($this->filename = basename($file['name']);** how i can set auto incremented name like a name + 1 and it should know if the last record filename is temp and new will be temp1 and new will be temp3
this should instead of my **(basename($file['name']);**

regards

Comment: do you absolutely have to do it that way? can you not add a random (or not necessarily random, better would be an incremented value or similar) prefix instead? e.g. `8v02rewm34m2034_temp.pdf`

Comment: ya that can be fine too

Comment: In that case you could use the incremental value or similar and just prepend it to the filename, possibly use some encryption or something on it to make it look more random (not sure if this may have any flaws). The prefix can be omitted when showing the file to your users (if you planned to) so to their knowledge the file name will be `temp.pdf` simply...

Answer (score 0):

i found it this way:

```
$rand_value = rand();
$this->filename = basename($rand_value."_".$file['name']);
```